# Objective-C Nullability: Qualifying Constant Strings

Tags: objective-c, swift, objective-c-nullability

I have gotten into a pretty good habit of declaring and using constant strings for things like `NSNotification` names. I declare them like so:

```
extern NSString * const ABCAwesomeThingHappenedNotification;
```

With the introduction of Xcode 6.3 and Swift 1.2, I'm going back and auditing Objective-C classes that interop with Swift using the new `nonnull`, `nullable`, and `null_unspecified` qualifiers.

When adding the qualifiers to a header that also has externally visible static strings, I receive the following warning:

> warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (__nonnull or __nullable)

Hmm. That's confusing / interesting. Can someone explain the reasoning behind this message? When using `ABCAwesomeThingHappenedNotification` in Swift, it never suggests that it's an optional String or implicitly unwrapped String.

Comment: Different question, but may also be interesting in this context: [Swift 1.2 optional external variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29612639/swift-1-2-optional-external-variable).

Comment: Related: [How to create class methods that conform to a protocol shared between Swift and Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29399871/how-to-create-class-methods-that-conform-to-a-protocol-shared-between-swift-and) (but this isn't a duplicate)

Comment: April, 2018. Still need to declare the __nonnull for extern * to avoid the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your implementation, you could define:

```
NSString * const ABCAwesomeThingHappenedNotification = @"ABCAwesomeThingHappenedNotification";
```

in which case the pointer is clearly `nonnull`. However, this is also valid:

```
NSString * const ABCAwesomeThingHappenedNotification = nil;
```

which must be considered `nullable` because the pointer is always a null pointer.

(The explicit initialisation to `nil` is redundant since this happens implicitly if no initial value is provided, but clarifies this example.)

Answer (score 34):

I agree that having this specifier shouldn't be required but here is syntax

```
extern NSString * const MyConstant;

extern NSString * __nonnull  const MyConstant;
```

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/2791584/lneuner: actually, since we are talking about the interface, this is the correct answer.

Comment: The question asks for the reasoning behind the warning, not the syntax to fix it.

Comment: I agree but when you don't know the answer then fix is like an answer.

Comment: April, 2018. Still need to declare the __nonnull for extern * to avoid the error.